# Extract everything before the matching string

Tags: text-processing

I have a string

```
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data/ip/list/usa/
```

and what I want is just

```
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//
```

i have tried awk, sed but I did not get what I was expecting because the match string `//` was repeating.
Is there a way to get my desired output?

Comment: What would you want if the input string was `hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data//ip/list/usa/`?

Comment: All I want is just `hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the first two strings with their match strings:

```
$ s=hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data/ip/list/usa/
$ echo "$s" | awk -F// '{print $1 FS $2 FS}'
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//
```

How it works:

- `-F//`

  This tells awk to use `//` as the field separator.
- `print $1 FS $2 FS`

  This tells awk to print the first field, a field separator, the second field, and another field separator.

#### Alternative

To obtain everything up to and including the last of the match strings:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk -F// '{$NF=""} 1' OFS=//
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//
```

How it works:

- `-F//`

  This tells awk to use `//` as the field separator for *input*.
- `$NF=""`

  This tells awk to replace the last field with the empty string.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-record.
- `OFS=//`

  This tells awk to use `//` as the field separator for *output*.

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy Explanation added.  As per your clarification, you want the first solution, not the one labeled "alternative."

Answer (score 1):

with `grep`

```
$ grep -o '^.*//.*//' <<< "hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data/ip/list/usa/"
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//

$ grep -oP '^.*?//.*?//' <<< "hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data/ip/list/usa/"
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//

$ grep -oP '^.*?com//' <<< "hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data/ip/list/usa/"
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//
```

- The first one works if there are only two sets of `//`
- The second one extracts upto the second set of `//`
- The third one works if required string ends with `com//`

**Edit:**

As @ilkkachu points out, `[^/]*` (zero or more characters, other than `/`) can be used instead of `.*?` in the second case. Example:

```
$ grep -o '^[^/]*//[^/]*//' <<< "hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data/ip/list/usa//"
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//
```

Comment: You could use `[^/]*` instead of `.*?`, to not require Perl regexes, since the matched part will not have slashes if it's a host name as it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the string in a shell variable, `var`, in `ksh` or `bash`:

```
$ var="hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com//data/ip/list/usa/"
$ printf "%s\n" "${var%//*}"
hdfs://ussbssn01.us.xyz.com
```

The `${var%suffix}` variable substitution will trim `suffix` off the value of `var`.