# Print the prefix of a file name up to a specific word

Tags: text-processing, filenames

I have a file name like below, and I want to print the file name before `.tar`. How I can do this?

Note: the part after `.tar` is fixed but the part before `.tar` is variable.

Example: `abcd_ef_1.2.3.12+all.tar.gz.md5sum`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153409/get-the-part-of-a-line-before-the-last-slash or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304150/extract-everything-before-the-matching-string

Answer (score 0):

Using sed for example:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)\.tar.*/\1/' <<< "abcd_ef_1.2.3.12+all.tar.gz.md5sum"
```

prints `abcd_ef_1.2.3.12+all`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ basename -s .tar.gz.md5sum 'abcd_ef_1.2.3.12+all.tar.gz.md5sum'
abcd_ef_1.2.3.12+all
```

With [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ s='abcd_ef_1.2.3.12+all.tar.gz.md5sum'
$ echo "${s%.tar*}"
abcd_ef_1.2.3.12+all
```

Answer (score 0):

combine find and sed maybe?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tar*" | sed 's/\(.*\)\(\.tar.*\)/\1/g'
```

explanation:
the first part of sed

```
\(.*\)\(\.tar.*\)
```

find the tar, but provide 2 grouping. 1 before the .tar and 1 after the tar

the second part of sed

```
\1
```

take only the first grouping(before the .tar)